# Dojo - iframe grab incoming html

Tags: html, iframe, dojo

I want to send post request to other domain with "dojo/request/iframe" (I use it because dojo.xhrPost not working , besause redirect).
After the site response I want to grab income html (I see that html in Firebug as response to iframe request). How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it pretty much like you would use xhr.

```
require(["dojo/request/iframe"], function(iframeRequest) {

    iframeRequest.post("/your/url", {
        handleAs: "html"
    }).then(function(response) {

        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(
            response.childNodes[0]);
    });
});
```

Keep in mind  that `response` is a `Document` object when you use `handleAs:"html"`, so you have to access its `childNodes` as above.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/iframe.html